# Resize image to one resolution

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, mogrify

I have a bunch of images, with different resolution.
Also there is a mix of landscape and portrait pictures. I need to resize the images to one resolution (1024x768). If i have a portrait picture, the max height needs to be 768, and my landscape pictures has to have a max width of 1024.

The space that is over, has to be made black.
Right now i use `mogrify -resize 1024x768 -verbose *.jpg`

I know i can use 1024x!768 , but like i said i'm using different kind of pictures. 
My exif information also doesn't contains information about if a picture is landscape or not.

Answer (score 1):

I use ImageMagick for such tasks. When installed, you have the "convert" command, which is very common, and does your task easyly.

Comment: Daniel: i also did see that tool indeed. Do you have some suggestions which parameters i need to use?

Comment: convert in.jpg -resize 1024x768 out.jpg! There are a lot of options. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize

Comment: Right now i have:  convert  -gravity center -resize 1024x768 -background black -extent 1024x768 *  but this still does resize the x or y asxis, it doesn't keep a notion of landscape/portrait

Answer (score 0):

You will have to crop the image to get the same aspect ratio, then you can resize the image to get the desired resolution. Example code using nodejs (imagemagick command line tools):

```
var width = 166;
var height = 117;
var ratio_new = width/height;
var ratio_old = image_file.width_orig/image_file.height_orig;
var pixels_too_much = 0;
var geometry = '';

if (ratio_old > ratio_new)
{
    config.debug && console.log ("remove horizontal pixel!");
    pixels_too_much = parseInt(image_file.width_orig - (image_file.height_orig * ratio_new))-1;
    geometry = parseInt(image_file.height_orig * ratio_new + 0.5) + 'x' + image_file.height_orig;
    geometry += "+" + parseInt(pixels_too_much/2) + "+0\!";
}
else if (ratio_old < ratio_new)
{
    config.debug && console.log ("remove vertikal pixel");
    pixels_too_much = parseInt(image_file.height_orig - (image_file.width_orig / ratio_new));
    geometry = image_file.width_orig + 'x' + (image_file.width_orig / ratio_new);
    geometry += "+0+" + parseInt(pixels_too_much/2)+"\!";
}
im.convert([image_file.path, '-crop', geometry, '-resize', width + 'x' + height, thumb_path],function(){});
```